# ¿como identificar carpetas?php

Tags: php

hola queria saber solo eso intente con filetype pero me sale un boleano

```
    function getDirectories(){
    $contenido=scandir($this->ruta);
    $directories=[];
    foreach ($contenido as $dir) {
         var_dump($dir);
         var_dump(filetype($dir));
        if(filetype($dir)=='dir' && (!$dir=='.'|| !$dir=='..')){
            $directories[]=$dir;
          }
    }
    $this->directories=$directories;
    return  $directories;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que estás sufriendo es debido a que [`scandir()`](http://php.net/scandir) te enumera el contenido del directorio, pero no incluye en los resultados la propia ruta del directorio, así que debes concatenar a cada resultado la ruta escaneada tú mismo:

```
function getDirectories(){
    $contenido = scandir($this->ruta);
    $directories = [];
    foreach ($contenido as $dir) {
        /* La ruta completa que debemos comprobar está compuesta por:
             - Ruta base
             - Constante de separador de rutas
             - El elemento de la enumeración obtenida con scandir()
        */
        if(is_dir($this->ruta . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $dir)) {
            $directories[] = $dir;
        }
    }
    $this->directories = $directories;
    return  $directories;
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

prueba con la función is_dir()

http://php.net/manual/es/function.is-dir.php

Saludos.

Comment: no. ya yo la había usado y tampoco funciona Gracias de todas formas